# How do I get the ob_start() callback to fire when getting the contents of the buffer?

Tags: php, output-buffering

I've got a script that runs a custom email obfuscation class's `Obfuscate()` function on the content before displaying it, as follows:

```
ob_start(array($obfuscator, "Obfuscate"));
include('header.php');
print($html);
include('footer.php');
ob_end_flush();
```

That all works great. However, I've completely rewritten my view architecture, so I need to run the email obfuscation from within a class function and return that string (which then gets `echo`ed). I initially rewrote the above as:

```
ob_start(array($this->obfuscator, "Obfuscate"));
include('header.php');
echo($this->content);
include('footer.php');
$wrappedContent = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Unfortunately, the `$this->obfuscator->Obfuscate()` callback is not being fired. I have since learned that `ob_get_contents()` does not fire the callback, but have tried `ob_get_clean()` & `ob_get_flush()` to no avail as well.

So, how can I get the contents of the buffer after the callback has been fired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, I was overlooking the fact that the only reason to use the callback on `ob_start()` was because I wanted to run `Obfuscate()` on the content before it was flushed, but if I'm getting that content back I *don't need to run a callback!* So, *not using a callback* and just running `ob_get_clean()`'s results through `Obfuscate()` does what I wanted. Doh!

```
ob_start();
include('header.php');
echo($this->content);
include('footer.php');
return $this->obfuscator->Obfuscate(ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: Me too thanks! Sometimes you got to side step to see the obvious solution

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ob_end_clean();
```

with

```
ob_clean()
```

Will trigger .

This is the code eg I tried

```
<?php
class Obfuscate {
    public function __construct() 
    {

    }

    public function getObfuscate()
    {
        return "obfuscate";
    }
}

class Example 
{
    public function hello( $obfuscator )
    {
        ob_start(array( $obfuscator, 'getObfuscate' ));
        include('header.php');
        echo "Thi is a content ";
        include('footer.php');
        $wrappedContent = ob_get_contents();
        ob_clean();
    }
}

$obfuscator = new Obfuscate();
$example = new Example;
$example->hello($obfuscator);
ob_clean();
```

Comment: How would calling `ob_clean()` after `ob_get_contents()` (which doesn't fire the callback) work?